# Dynamic filename in gulp-zip

Tags: gulp, gulp-zip

I try to generate multiple zip files with [gulp-zip](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-zip)

```
packages
- package-1
- package-2
```

to

```
build
- package-1.zip
- package-2.zip
```

At the moment my task looks like this:

```
gulp.task('zip', function () {
    return gulp.src("packages/*")
    .pipe(zip("archive.zip"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build"));
});
```

This generates a single zip file names **archive.zip** which contains my two packages.

How to get 2 separate zipfiles?

How to pass the folder name to the zip function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the zip command twice in your zip task, like so:

```
gulp.task('zip', function () {
    gulp.src("packages/package-1/**")
        .pipe(zip("archive-1.zip"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("build"));
    return gulp.src("packages/package-2
        .pipe(zip("archive-2.zip"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("build"));
});
```

This will result in 2 zip-files in your build folder. Hope this helps.